How to get sales channel ID from a product in Shopware 6?
Simple question, but I can't find a solution.
I'm trying to get the sales channel ID in Shopware 6 programmatically, but I'm not succeeding!
// This will fetch product object successfully
$product = $this->productRepository->search($productCriteria, $context)->first();

// This will throw Exception
$salesChannelId = $product->getSalesChannelId();

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Add association to your criteria:
$productCriteria->addAssociation('visibilities');

The visibilities control in which sales channel the product should be visible.
$product->getVisibilities();


Additional documentation that will help you:

Reading Data - Associations


Thank U very much!
So, code geeting salesChannelId will be:
$product->getVisibilities()->getSalesChannelId();

